# Why does the gradient of function $f$ only exists for function that outputs scalars?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

I am studying matrix calculus and I don't quite understand why the gradient only exists for functions that take $m \times n$ matrices as input and that output a scalar, i.e., functions of the type $\mathbb R^{m \times n} \to \mathbb R$.

Comment: Well, for function whose outputs are vectors the gradient has another name: the Jacobian. For which other kinds of function do you think gradient should be defined?

Comment: @Crostul Ah I see. So the term gradient is solely to differentiate between $f:\Re^{m\times n}\implies \Re$ from $f:\Re^{m\times n}\implies \Re^{a\times b}$. I'm guessing gradient has special properties that jacobian doesn't have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **gradient** of a *differentiable* function $f : \mathbb R^{m \times n} \to \mathbb R$

$$\nabla f (\mathrm X) : \mathbb R^{m \times n} \to \mathbb R^{m \times n}$$

is the *matrix-valued* function that produces the **directional derivative** of $f$ in the direction of $\mathrm V \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ at $\mathrm X \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ via the following [Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product)

$$\langle \mathrm V, \nabla f (\mathrm X) \rangle$$

If the output of a function is *not* a scalar, then its directional derivative will *not* be a scalar either. Hence, there is no way of producing the directional derivative via some inner product, as inner products produce scalars (by definition).